# How can I know what version of Jinja2 my ansible is using?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I tried to use `pip list` and `pip freeze` without success.
It might be something obvious but I am not able to find it so far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Drop this file as `./action_plugins/jin_ver.py`:

```
from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase
import jinja2


class ActionModule(ActionBase):

    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        result = super(ActionModule, self).run(tmp, task_vars)
        return dict(msg=jinja2.__version__)
```

And execute this playbook `./test_jin.yaml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - action: jin_ver
```

You should see something like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook test_jin.yaml -v
TASK [jin_ver] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "msg": "2.8"}
```

Comment: This worked, but i had to execute the playbook with a -v flag. Thanks !

Comment: To future me: once you've checked (thanks to this answer) that ansible uses the _wrong_ version of Jinja, go check Yeroc's answer to fix it.

Answer (score 12):

The answer to this could vary somewhat depending on your platform but generally:

```
$ pip show jinja2
Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.2.1
Summary: A small but fast and easy to use stand-alone template engine written in pure python.
...
```

If you're on a platform where python and related dependencies are installed via a package manager then you could also check that way.  For example on RHEL:

```
$ rpm -q python-jinja2
python-jinja2-2.2.1-3.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: Nice!. "Name: Jinja2 Version: 3.1.2" little confuse me :-)