# Problem with map when the key does not exist

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a var_file with this format:

```yaml
bds_info:

  - id:   BD1
    db_name: BD1
    db_port: XXXX
    server: server1
    repo_url: repo1

  - id:   BD2
    db_name: BD2
    db_port: XXXX
    server: server2
    repo_url: repo2
    scan_name: scan2
```

What I'm trying to do is to select the scan_name from the var_file into a variable like this:

```yaml
var_scan_name_to_use:       "{{ (bds_info   | selectattr('id', 'equalto', (db_name|upper) ) | map(attribute='scan_name') | join) }}"
```

it works correctly if the id selected has the key but if it hasn't then I get the following error:

```json
{
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'scan_name
}
```

Is it possible to return undefined instead of a lookup error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can specify a `default` value to use if an object in the list does not have the given attribute.
>
> ```
> {{ users|map(attribute="username", default="Anonymous")|join(", ") }}
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map*</sup>

---

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        bds_info
          | selectattr('id', 'equalto', db_name | upper)
          | map(attribute='scan_name', default='undefined')
          | join
      }}
  vars:
    db_name: BD1
    bds_info:
      - id: BD1
        db_name: BD1
        db_port: XXXX
        server: server1
        repo_url: repo1
      - id: BD2
        db_name: BD2
        db_port: XXXX
        server: server2
        repo_url: repo2
        scan_name: scan2
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: undefined
```

Comment: I tried your solution and got:

{
    "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ bds_info   | selectattr('id', 'equalto', db_name|upper ) | map(attribute='scan_name', default='undefined') | join }}'. Error was a <class 'jinja2.exceptions.FilterArgumentError'>, original message: Unexpected keyword argument 'default'",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}

Comment: What are your versions of Ansible (`ansible --version`) and Jinja? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040013/how-can-i-know-what-version-of-jinja2-my-ansible-is-using/49040559)

Comment: Ansible 2.9.9 and Jinja 2.10.3

Comment: Then this is why: *Changed in version 2.11.0: Added the default parameter.*. You might want to consider getting your Jinja version a little bit more up to date.

Comment: I'm in the same boat here, but thankfully the other answer works in that case. Sometimes we can't upgrade versions we would like to...

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem similar to yours. I was trying to do something like this:

```
groups.some_group | map('extract', hostvars, 'some_var') | default('default_value')
```

But I got the same error: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable..."

I did also try to use the keyword 'default' as a map parameter:

```
groups.some_group | map('extract', hostvars, 'some_var', default='default_value')
```

But this time I got the error "An unhandled exception occurred..."

What did really work for me was passing the data through 'default' filter using map():

```
groups.some_group | map('extract', hostvars, 'some_var') | map('default', 'default_value')
```

The solution above worked on "ansible [core 2.15.1]"

Comment: Thank you!  I had a role that worked fine for months and suddenly needed this.

Comment: Thanks for this, this was a perfect workaround for me.