# Ansible - Jinja2 template with import encounters undefined variable

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

My playbook calls the following task :

```
name: Mytask
    template:
       src: "path/to/template.j2"
       dest: "/dest/file"
       mode: '755'
```

This template uses the variable {{ organization }} then import a jinja macro with the keyword *with context*

```
{% for organization in organization _list %}
  - name: Loading 
    include_vars:
      file: "{{ config_file_dir }}/{{ organization }}/{{ file_name }}"
      name: "platform_file"

{% from 'another_template.j2' import function_name as name with context %}
{{ name(param1, param2) }}


{% endfor %}
```

and finally the imported jinja macro, here I get an *undefined variable {{ organization }}* when trying to print it.

```
{% macro function_name(param1, param2) %}
{{ organization|pprint }}
{% endmacro %}
```

The variable is defined when passed to the first template but it doesn't follow the import inside that template, same issue for an include with context.

I am running ansible in version 2.9.21 and Python 2.7.12 (need python 2.7 for a library incompatible with python 3)

Comment: From what I remember `import` has been added "recently" to Jinja. [What is your version of Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040013/how-can-i-know-what-version-of-jinja2-my-ansible-is-using)?

Comment: Solved after upgrading python and ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after upgrading python and ansible